# Git pull change log

Tags: git, logging, commit, pull

After pulling from a git server, I'm trying to get a list of all changed files. I don't need any specific parts of code, just a list of files (with some kind of indication as to wether it's been added, removed or changed).

I first looked at using git log, but that appearantly only returns info from the last commit:

`git log --name-status --max-count=1 --pretty=format:""`

Since this appearantly only gets the changes from the last commit in a pull, I'm trying to find a way to get all the changes (the pull almost always exists out of multiple commits).

Is there any command for this? (I'm interacting with Git from PHP, btw)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a pull, `ORIG_HEAD` refers to where you were before, and `HEAD` refers to where you are now. So `ORIG_HEAD..` means the changes pulled into the current branch. `--max-count=1` means just the last commit, not what you want, as you discovered.

You probably want something like `git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..` which will output a single-character status code and a filename for each file changed, aggregating all the commits together. If you want it broken down by each change, you need something like `git log --oneline --name-status ORIG_HEAD..`

Comment: `git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..` worked like a charm, can't say thank you enough!

Comment: `alias gpull='git pull; git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..'` Just what I wanted, added this to my .bashrc

Comment: This doesn't work as desired if you have your remote tracking branch tracking a different branch. For example, if I have my branch `topic` tracking `origin/master`. Pull will rebase `topic` onto `origin/master`. To see the delta introduced only on the upstream branch, you can run `git lg @{1}..@{u}`. `@{1}` uses reflogs and is the same as `ORIG_HEAD`. `@{u}` is your upstream branch (remote tracking branch)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative command is:

```
git pull --stat
```