# How to show "new" commits in git

Tags: git, version-control

I do

```
git pull
```

to get new commits from remote and merge them with my local branch.

How can I list the commits that "just came in" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535150/git-pull-change-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in a specific branch (e.g., `master`), you can take the line in the output of `git fetch` that has that branch's name:

```
6ec1a9c..91f6e69  master     -> origin/master
```

and use it to construct a `git log` command

```
git log --graph --decorate 6ec1a9c..91f6e69
```

The two periods mean "all commits that are in the second commit (origin/master) but are not in the first (master)", which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```
git log @{1}..
```

This is the same as

```
git log currentbranch@{1}..currentbranch
```

where the `@{1}` notation means "the commit the branch pointed to just before it last got updated".

This shows you exactly the commits that got merged.

Answer (score 4):

If you do `git pull` it automatically merges the commits; You can't look at just the new ones but `git log` will give you a list of all commits.

If you merely `fetch`ed the commits you could possibly list them before merging, but I think that might be slightly pointless.

**Edit**: A quick glance at the Internet seems to tell me that `git log -p ..FETCH_HEAD` would list fetched but unmerged commits, as a fun fact of sorts, in case you ever find yourself needing to see only the fetched commits.

**Another**: ellotheth's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535150/git-pull-change-log) in their comment seems to have a solution that even works with pull. It seems to use `git diff` but maybe `git log ORIG_HEAD..` or similar would work, too?

...Nevertheless, using `fetch` and `merge` instead of `pull` might actually be the sensible thing to do, especially if you are assuming you don't necessarily want to merge all the commits immediately, or at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
git log --topo-order
```

should work.

It is supposed to show the log entries in the order they came to the current branch - not the chronological order.

Comment: Do you know where this argument is documented?

Comment: Nevermind, [found it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering) on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I would defer you to

> `git help log`

to see the options that may help your case. Perhaps you are wanting the `--first-parent` option?

I personally do this a lot:

> `git log -n 5 --oneline`

Comment: `git log -n 5` is not sufficient as the new commits might be a not the top-most entries (if they were comited a month a go but pushed today)

Answer (score 1):

First call `git fetch`
Then:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative master..origin/master
```

This will show something like this:

```
* d3e3a17 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Fix test (3 minutes ago)
* a065a9c - Fix exec count (4 minutes ago)
```

Related: [How do I see the commit differences between branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965391/how-do-i-see-the-commit-differences-between-branches-in-git/48258629#48258629)

Answer (score -1):

it's

```
git log
```

you are looking for

[doc about git log](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Comment: let's suppose your last commit were 2 weeks ago, then with `git log --after="2 weeks ago"` will display the log from today to 2 weeks ago. Hope this could help.

Comment: Still this would not do the job if somebody commited something 4 weeks ago but did not push. He pushes now and I pull. So I would not see his commit as "new".