# how do I get a diff of each commit in a branch

Tags: git, github

This questions is similar to: [How do I see the commit differences between branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965391/how-do-i-see-the-commit-differences-between-branches-in-git)

but I would like to see the diff for each commit separately, allowing me to find problems in a commit and modifying the commit with rebase -i before uploading to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git log -u`  ... checkout `git help log`

```
   -p, -u, --patch
       Generate patch (see section on generating patches).
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `git log` to see the list of commits. Then get the `SHA-1` of the commit you want to see and do a `git show <SHA-1 of commit>`