# Difference between double-dot ".." and caret / hat symbol "^" in git

Tags: git

When I want to find the commits that are in branch `A` but not in branch `B` I often write

```
git log A ^ B
```

But according to the SO post 
[How do I see the commit differences between branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965391/how-do-i-see-the-commit-differences-between-branches-in-git) the following does the same thing:

```
git log B..A
```

Are these commands identical? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for `git log` covering History Simplification we find:

> **--ancestry-path**
>   When given a range of commits to display (**e.g. commit1..commit2 or commit2 ^commit1**), only display commits that exist directly on the ancestry chain between the commit1 and commit2, i.e. commits that are both descendants of commit1, and ancestors of commit2.

It seems from the documentation itself that either `git log ^ B` and `git log A..B` behave identically, and the `^` and `..` operators can be used interchangeably with `git log`.

Comment: They are different operators, just in this case they gave the same result. E.g. You could have multiple `^commit-ish` in one line

Comment: @Alexey Yes, my answer specifically says that these operators are interchangeable in the case of `git log`.

Comment: On a side note: It would be more accurate to consider `A..B` a shorthand of `A ^B`, since the `^` operator can be used for more complex ref specs. Such a spec could simply take the form of `A ^B ^C`.