# git show only lines that my actual branch miss from other branch

Tags: git

I have my `develop branch` which has already been merged with my `feature/fix branch`. My `develop` has more `feature` branches already merged and is ahead of the `feature/fix` with a lot of commits.

How could I get git to show me only the LINES of code in the FILES that `feature/fix` has but `develop` doesn't have. I don't want to show what `develop` has and `feature/fix` doesn't have.

Comment: Look at this GIT cheat sheet : 
https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/6814451

Check out how to compare branches, I think that should be a solution to your problem.

Comment: can't see how this would help me @RannLifshitz . none of those lines under "compare" exclude differences on one side. Thanks

Comment: How about this thread from SO?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965391/how-do-i-see-the-commit-differences-between-branches-in-git

Comment: When you say "only the lines", do you mean "only the commits"?

Comment: nope, i mean lines in files @MarinosAn

Comment: But still it is a little vague. Is it: "print all the lines of files(that exist only in `feature/fix`)" OR "print only lines that exist only in file versions of `feature/fix`"? I have an answer for both.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all the commits that `feature/fix` has but `develop` does not have.

```
git log develop..feature/fix
```

Be aware that the output might be different than:

```
git log origin/develop..origin/feature/fix
```

For the latter command make sure you have performed `git fetch` first.