# git cherry master upstream vs upstream master

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick, git-cherry

I am a bit confused as to what the logical difference here is between `git cherry master upstream` and `git cherry upstream master`. I get that it former is probably the more correct one to apply, but I don't exactly get why the list is much longer the other way.

Say I have two branches `master` and `feature`. Now let's say that I have commits in `feature` but I also have some commits in `master` that I want in `feature` and vice versa, but can't (or won't) merge these two branches. The way to go about such peculiar management nightmare would be to cross-cherry-pick the commits I needed.

As a result, why do `git cherry feature master` and `git cherry master feature` produce different results and is there any way to get a complete and reliable list of the discrepancy between these branches?

Comment: There are some good ans here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965391/how-do-i-see-the-commit-differences-between-branches-in-git