# How do I see git log in the order the changes arrived at my machine not when they were committed?

Tags: git

Maybe a dumb question but:

Something broke my build after a git pull. I check the logs and nothing has changed since my last build! Der, lots of stuff has changed but it changed 6 months ago and has only just been pushed to the remote repository. So looking at the log it's buried way down past the date of my last (good) build.

How do I see a log of what has changed since my last pull? Or has been pushed since a given date? I don't care when it was changed or when it was committed. I do care when it turned up in my build tree and when it was pushed into my current branch of the remote repos.

I've looked at [Git and log order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886001/git-and-log-order) but that doesn't seem to be the same question so kicking off a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git pull change log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535150/git-pull-change-log)

Comment: So have you not pulled in 6 months or is this a branch that was merged into the one you're building off recently but the commits on that branch were created 6 months ago?

Comment: Try `git log @{u} ^@{u}@{1}`

Comment: A branch that was merged into the one I'm building off recently but the commits on that branch were created 6 months ago.

Comment: git log @{u} ^@{u}@{1} shows me a few recent commits - what should it do?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to view the log ordered by date, you need to find when did the problem begun.

To do so you can use any of the followings:

1. You can use `git reflog` to view your local git history and determine whats went wrong and from which point.

It will print out the commit log so you will be able to trace your whole git pull history.

it will look something like:

```
c37166e HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
95d26a4 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
....
5ec6544 HEAD@{n}: checkout .... (or whatever was before)
```

once you find out the exact point when all went wrong, checkout the branch at this point and compare it to your last good state.

---

2. use `git bisect`

`git bisect` will "find" the exact point in the commit log when all the troubles begun.

Git bisect is very simple to use. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect) is a very detailed answer about git bisect

Comment: Actually I'm oversimplifying the situation - but I need to see what changes have been introduced between pulls. I can't believe git can't tell me that - it seems the first thing a collab tool should do! Surely I'm missing something?

Comment: `git diff SHA1 SHA2` will show the changes between 2 commits, if you want only the file names without the content add the ` --name-only` flag